# Bad request using request.value

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am creating an app with a friend's network. The user can friend people and a list of friends will appear in the user's homepage, as a list of links that ideally would lead to the friends profile page.

So what I am doing now, is to render the friends list on the users home page. Then when the user clicks on one of the friend links  I use JS to save the ID of the clicked element in a variable 'x' and then send this variable via ajax to the server. On the server a function(friends_profile) listens on the link's route and gets the value of 'x' via request.value['x']  .

Then I use the value of 'x' to query a database and get the friends info that will be displayed on the friends-profile.html page. 
And here is where I am stuck, the friends profile never loads, I get a Bad request error.

On the terminal window I see: GET /friends_Profile?x=1 HTTP/1.0" 200 
and then 
GET /friends_Profile HTTP/1.0" 400

I can also print the value of 'x' (in this case 1) from the friends_profile() function so I know the value of 'x' is in the server, but I can't understand why I get a bad request.

Is it a syntax error?

Or do I go about this completely the wrong way? I also welcome any other Ideas on how to solve this problem.

I am using Flask, python, HTML and JS

Here's some code:

JS to define the value of 'x' and send to is to the server:

```
(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){

    let x = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax("/friends_Profile?x="+x)
```

Here is the function on the server:

```
@app.route('/friends_Profile', methods=["GET"])
def friends_profile():
    userid = request.values['x']
    print(userid)
    print(type(userid))

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT Name FROM users WHERE rowid = ?", userid)
    info = c.fetchall()

    print(info[0][0])
    print('line 464')


    return render_template('friends-profile.html', friend=info)
```

Don't know if you need the HTML, but here is
all the HTML involved(1/2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/, alternative themes at https://bootswatch.com/ -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- https://favicon.io/emoji-favicons/money-mouth-face/ -->
        <link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

        <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-light bg-dark border ">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/main"><span class="red">DBSF</span></a>
            <li class="navbar-brand">
                <div class="dropdown">

                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Groups
                </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        {% for x in range(2) %}
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Friend {{loop.index}} </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/groups">Create New Group</a>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </li>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/activities"><span class="blue">Planned Activities</span></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/messages"><span class="yellow">Messages</span></a>
        <li class="navbar-brand">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                My Profile
                </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/my_profile">Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/log_out">Log Out</a>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </li>



        </nav>
      <div class="side-bar-activities">
        <br>
        <br>
        <b>Activities</b>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.bowlero.com/" target="_blank">Bowling</a>
          <li><a href="https://www.battlecreekpaintballnj.com/" target="_blank">Paintball</a>
          <li><a href="https://rpmraceway.com/" target="_blank">Go Karts</a>
          <li><a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r" target="_blank">Game night</a>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=bars+near+me&oq=bars+near+me&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2269j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8" target="_blank">Drinks</a>

        </ul>
        <div class="memories">
          <b>Things you did with your Friends:</b>

        </div>
      </div>
        <div class='call-list'>
          <br>
          <br>
          <b>You haven't called so and so in a while</b>
          <ul>
            <li> Your sister</li>
            <li> Marissa</li>
            <li> Ester</li>
            <li> Luca</li>
            <li> Patrick</li>
          </ul>
          <div class='friends'>
            <b>You are Friends with:</b>
            {% for x in range(friends|length) %}
            <li><a id='{{friends[loop.index-1][0][0]}}'
            method='POST, GET' href='/friends_Profile' name='{{friends[loop.index-1][0][1]}}_{{friends[loop.index-1][0][2]}}'>{{friends[loop.index -1][0][1]}} {{friends[loop.index -1][0][2]}}</a></li>

            {% endfor %}

      </div>
        </div>




        <main>
            {% block main %}{% endblock %}
        </main>
      <footer>

      </footer>


    </body>


</html>
```

HTML (2/2):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Beginning
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <title>DBSF</title>

{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}

<br>
  <p class='flashes'>{{message}}<p>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
<button id='click' class='btn btn-primary'>Click</button>
<h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>
<p> You are doing great, just a little step every day</p>
<div>
  <b>Things to do:</b>
  <br>
  <br>
    <li> Connect users/friends
    <br> <b>BOOOOOMMM</b>
    <br> <p>DONE!!! ! I still think my way would have worked better</p></li>
  <br>
    <li> JS Alert on login istead of new page .... si lo so..</li>
    <br> <b>BINGPOT</b>
    <br> <p>DONE!!! request.args.get gets the word after $.get('/route?THIS HERE=' +...)</p>
    <br> <p>You did it.....</p>
  <br>
    <li> improove layout</li>
    <br>

    <li>save a picture to database</li>
    <b>DONE EVRYONE GETS A UNIQUE PROFILE PIC</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Messaging system</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Page for Friends profile</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Meat and Potato of this app, <br>keep track of user interaction and render users that have't been contacted in a while...yep...<br>
    good Luck
    <p>with javascript, use on click and send an increment <br>with a time stamp to a function that renders friends if theuy haven't been clicked <on class=""></on></p></li>





</div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    let clicks = 0;
    $('#click').click(function(){
      clicks ++;
      console.log(clicks +' ' + Date());

    });
  });


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){

    let x = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax("/friends_Profile?x="+x)

  });
});
</script>




 {% endblock %}

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Beginning
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <title>DBSF</title>

{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}

<br>
  <p class='flashes'>{{message}}<p>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
<button id='click' class='btn btn-primary'>Click</button>
<h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>
<p> You are doing great, just a little step every day</p>
<div>
  <b>Things to do:</b>
  <br>
  <br>
    <li> Connect users/friends
    <br> <b>BOOOOOMMM</b>
    <br> <p>DONE!!! ! I still think my way would have worked better</p></li>
  <br>
    <li> JS Alert on login istead of new page .... si lo so..</li>
    <br> <b>BINGPOT</b>
    <br> <p>DONE!!! request.args.get gets the word after $.get('/route?THIS HERE=' +...)</p>
    <br> <p>You did it.....</p>
  <br>
    <li> improove layout</li>
    <br>

    <li>save a picture to database</li>
    <b>DONE EVRYONE GETS A UNIQUE PROFILE PIC</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Messaging system</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Page for Friends profile</li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li>Meat and Potato of this app, <br>keep track of user interaction and render users that have't been contacted in a while...yep...<br>
    good Luck
    <p>with javascript, use on click and send an increment <br>with a time stamp to a function that renders friends if theuy haven't been clicked <on class=""></on></p></li>





</div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    let clicks = 0;
    $('#click').click(function(){
      clicks ++;
      console.log(clicks +' ' + Date());

    });
  });


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){

    let x = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax("/friends_Profile?x="+x)

  });
});
</script>




 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Look up the HTML response codes. If you're running Flask, check in your console window to see what errors it produces. ***POST YOUR CODE*** so we can help.

Comment: Added some code...

Comment: run in debug mode and maybe it shows more information about problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if `execute()` doesn't need tuple with arguments even if you have only one value -  `execute(query, (userid,))` - It has to be `,` in `(userid,)` to create tuple

Comment: yeah that's true, but it still didn't fix the problem....

Comment: You list `GET /friends_Profile?x=1 HTTP/1.0" 200` and `GET /friends_Profile HTTP/1.0" 400` in your terminal window. Are these two different requests? What is this terminal window?

Comment: how do I run debug mode??

Comment: @bcr666 One is from the ajax "GET /friends_Profile?x=2 HTTP/1.0" 200 and the other one from the href in the html GET /friends_Profile HTTP/1.0 both appear in the same terminal window...

Comment: So a 400 Bad request is sent by the server when you make a request that it doesn't recognize. Since your requests only differ by the passing of a parameter, I'd bet that that is your problem so in the href in the html, add the `?x=...`.

Comment: @bcr666 what would I put for ... ??

Comment: @bcr666 It worked i put: href='/friends_Profile?x={{friends[loop.index-1][0][0]}}'and it worked as expected...thank you so much it's been driving me nuts for days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way your Python Flask API is coded, it mandatorily expects a query parameter "x" (in lowercase), whenever you hit the endpoint "/friends_Profile" through a GET method. So i think, the "href" will be fired when click on the list item, which would eventually invoke the api without Query parameter "x". I guess, this is what your issue is. Please correct this and let me know, if this works.

```
<li><a id='{{friends[loop.index-1][0][0]}}'
        method='POST, GET' href='/friends_Profile' name='{{friends[loop.index-1][0][1]}}_{{friends[loop.index-1][0][2]}}'>{{friends[loop.index -1][0][1]}} {{friends[loop.index -1][0][2]}}</a></li>
```

Comment: I changed the the href to: href='/friends_Profile?x={{friends[loop.index-1][0][0]}}' and it worked as expected...thanks everyone for the amazing help...it has been driving me nuts for days

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```py
userid = request.values['x']
```

to

```py
userid = request.args.get('x')
```

then you can run a check to see if `x` returns anything by doing this:

```py
if userid is None:
    # some code if userid is blank
else:
    # some code if userid has a value
```

be sure to add `from Flask import request` at the top of your code file.

Hope this helps. :)